# Whenever I try to log to wordpress admin I get The page isn't redirecting properly error message

Tags: wordpress

The frontend works correctly, it's only when trying to log in the backend that the error occurs.

On the frontend, I can see that I'm logged in (the black ribbon on the top), when I click on any link I get this error message too

```
Content Encoding Error
```

I tried everything I found on the web. Disabled plugins, updated WordPress and the theme to no avail.
I tried the same code on my local machine, and it's working flawlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to fix this issue thanks to @jpg0002 in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058647/wordpress-wp-admin-redirect-loop-yet-again).

There were too many configurations on my vhost. I have simplified it and I can access the admin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a MySQL server older than version 5.5.3, you might need to change your tables' character encoding back to utf8.

[This](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/content-encoding-error-16) might also help